# Index Match with Duplicate Values and Blank Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to reference a single row, different status and their corresponding date. Each of these values is stored in columns with affiliated (=duplicate) references and under each status there are blank cells. The only good thing, values are asserted from largest to smallest under each corresponding status. Hence, I need to match a specific condition to retrieve the Nth (smallest or largest) value instead of the first match.

[image: ImageIssue]

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1365981/edit) with more information. You may also want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it is, we don't even know if the screen capture you provide is existing data or expected output. It would also be useful to know what you've tried so far and how it differs from the expected output.

Comment: This might apply: https://superuser.com/questions/1356819/excel-index-match-large-with-2-criteria/1357679#comment2039481_1357679

Comment: Hey thank you both I'm a bit of a novice though. Well the screenshot is a simplification of the data I have (>10'000 rows) so it's existing data and the left table is the Output I'd like to get. Using an Index( Match;Match) formula list the first outcome which is blank for status different from approved (because of the way data is listed in the left table). I'd like to extract the SMALLEST Initiated date and the LARGEST Withdrawn date but I don't exactly know how to input it in the Index(Match;Match) formula though. Cheers for any hints

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using array formulas.  Instead of using the header values (initiated, withdrawn, etc) I created separate formulas for each column.  This simplifies the approach and should not be a burden unless you have a lot of status columns.  I also assume that you would want these formulas starting in row 3.

[image: Sample]

Note: Both of these are array formulas and you will need to enter as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (CSE).

Put them into the designated cell, CSE, and then drag them down.

***`K3`:***

`{=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$14,MATCH(1,(I3=$C$2:$C$14)*(MIN((IF($E$2:$E$14="",1000000,$E$2:$E$14))*(IF(I3=$C$2:$C$14,1,1000000)))=$E$2:$E$14),0),0),"")}`

To get the `MIN` to work properly in an array formula I had to use `IF` statements that return `1,000,000` when it doesn't match your reference or is blank.  That value is just an arbitrary number and just needs to be larger than any date value.  (Remember, dates are stored as numbers and `1,000,000` would be a date sometime in the year 4637!)  Without this, the `MIN` function finds the lowest value in the array, which will be `0`.

***`L3`:***

`{=INDEX($F$2:$F$14,MATCH(1,(I3=$C$2:$C$14)*(MAX(($F$2:$F$14)*(I3=$C$2:$C$14))=$F$2:$F$14),0),0)}`

Notice that the formula in column L will return `0` if nothing found.  Rather than complicate the formula, you can just set formatting to be `dd.mm.yy;;;@`, which will hide the zero value.  The formula in column K will return an error if nothing found, so I wrapped it in an `IFERROR` statement.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Write this Formula in Cell `G2` & fill down.

   ```
   {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$F$11, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($G$1:G1, $A$2:$A$11), 0)),"")}
   ```

**N.B.** *This is an array formula and 
          must be confirmed with 
          `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.*

2. In Cell `H2` write this Array formula, 
   confirm with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and 
   fill down.

   ```
    {=Text(MIN(IF(($A$2:$A$11=G2)*($C$2:$C$11>0),$C$2:$C$11," ")),"dd.mm.yy;;;@")}
   ```
3. Write this Array Formula in Cell `I2` 
   finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & 
   fill down.

   ```
    {=Text(MAX(IF(($A$2:$A$11=G2)*($D$2:$D$11>0),$D$2:$D$11,"")),"dd.mm.yy;;;@")}
   ```
4. Array Formula in Cell `J2` must be finished with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.

   ```
   {=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$11, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($J$1:J1, $E$2:$E$11), 0)),"")}
   ```

**Note:**

1. Adjust cell references in the Formula 
   as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Dears, thank you for your answers, I've figured out somne easier way to match and excerpt these data.

Formula to retrieve the smallest value:
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1000000;1/(($A$2:$A$3169=G2)*($B$2:$B$3169<>""));$B$2:$B$3169);"")

Formula to retrieve the largest value
=IFERROR(INDEX(D$2:D$3149;MATCH(1;--($A$2:$A$3149=$G2)*--(D$2:D$3149<>"");0);1);"")

Regards,[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI8MO.png)