# How to Extract the Smallest 10 Values for 83 Counties

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to extract the smallest 10 low response scores for each of the 83 different counties in our state.  I've tried using the following "SMALL" & "IF" functions with no luck:

{=SMALL(IF(County_name="Alcona County",Low_Response_Score),F7)}

where:

County_name=defined array of all 83 county names
Low_Response_Score=defined array of all low response values for all counties
F7=nth smallest value for the request

However, excel is returning the nth smallest value for the entire range of values for all 83 counties, not the nth smallest value for only Alcona county.
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us a representation of your data? What are the score values?

Comment: Please click on `edit` above to the left, and either add an example, or add a weblink to a URL which has an example (such as you might make with Imgur.com https://imgur.com/upload

Comment: I think that `MATCH` is what you need instead of `IF`.  This link uses `LARGE` instead of `SMALL`, but the principle is the same and may be of help:  https://superuser.com/questions/1356819/excel-index-match-large-with-2-criteria/1357679#comment2039481_1357679

Comment: how do you break a tie, or are they all unique values?

Comment: Please provide a sample data source about your problem. Normally you can use SMALL function to get the result directly, but not sure what's the conditional for your requirement.

Comment: "10 low response scores for each of the 83 .." so you are listing / catching a 830 line of data? right?